# Armeria API to close HTTP connection from server-side

Tags: armeria

We use Armeria as a mock HTTP server to test negative scenarios like delayed responses and unexpected error status codes etc.

Now we have a requirement where we need to close a connection so that we can test what the client does in `connection reset by peer` kinds of scenarios. What is the best way to do this from the server-side? Is this to be done via a "decorator" ? A link to the API or example code would be great.